# UUID field in MongoDB using Rails and mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I need a uuid field.
I know, that Mongo has native UUID support and UUID function.
What I want something like this

```
field :uuid, type: String, default: 'UUID()'
```

Of course, in this case it will be just 'UUID()' string.

Is there a way to really execute this function upon creating a record?
There is simular functionality in ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try before_save:

```
class MyModel
  include Mongoid::Document
  before_save :generate_uuid  
  field :uuid,  type: String  
 
  def generate_uuid
    code_to_generate_uuid
  end
 end
```

The BSON::ObjectId is pretty much a UUID though so this may be overkill

Comment: Here uuid generated at ruby level, question was at native (mongodb) level

Comment: It looks like Mongoid doesn't support this out of the box. There is a `mongoid-uuid` gem you could install to give you a `.uuid` method, which you could call in the before_save method.

Comment: If the question is about uuid generation in MongoDB server you should write that. Right now the answer answers the question as the question is written.